# numpy n-dimensional smart indexing over large tensors - memory efficiency

Tags: numpy, indexing, theano

I'm working with large tensors, so numpy memory allocations for temporary tensors begin significantly influencing execution time + code sometimes raises memory allocation errors during those intermediate steps. Here're two approaches for indexing one tensor with `int` values of another tensor (like, `result_ijk = a[i, b[i, j], k]`) that I came up with, and even though second one seems more memory-efficient, I feel like creating this enormous index-matrix and iterating over all it's values (even in parallel) is kind of wired (and hits memory limits quite often):

```
def test():
    i, j, k, l = 10, 20, 30, 40 # in reality, they're like 1e3..1e6
    a = np.random.rand(i, j, k)
    b = np.random.randint(0, j, size=i*l).reshape((i, l))
    # c_ilk = c[i, b[i, l], k]; shape(c) = (10, 40, 30)
    tmp = a[:, b, :] # <= i*ijk additional memory allocated (!) crazy
    c1 = np.diagonal(tmp, axis1=0, axis2=1).transpose([2, 0, 1])
    print(c1.shape)
    # another approach:
    ii, ll = np.indices((i, l)) # <= 2*i*l of temporary ints allocated
    tmp2 = b[ii, ll] # i*l of ints allocated, slow ops
    c2 = a[ii, tmp2] # slow ops over tensor
    print(c2.shape)
    print(np.allclose(c1, c2))

test()
```

- any suggestions on how one could optimize this type of n-dim smart indexing code?

If I'm going to use this piece of ~vectorized code in Theano, does it also going to allocate all those temporary buffers or it could somehow manage to build them "on-fly"? Is there any package that would perform such indexing in lazy\more efficient manner without allocation of these `ii`-like tensors?

(note: I need to take gradients over it in the end, so I can't use fancy jit-compilers like `numba` :( )

Comment: Seems to me like i*l is small compared to the totality of your data, so your second method seems fine to me. I would be highly surprised if this turned out to be the actual bottleneck in your complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to allocate an array of integers of length `i` to get your desired result:

```
i_idx = np.arange(i)
c = a[i_idx[:, None], b[i_idx, :], :]
# or you can use the terser c = a[i_idx[:, None], b[i_idx]]
```

Broadcasting takes care of duplicating values as needed on the fly, without having to allocate memory for them.

If you time this for large-ish arrays, you'll notice it is only marginally faster than your second approach: as noted by others, the intermediate indexing array is going to be several orders of magnitude smaller than your overall computation, so optimizing it has a small effect on the total runtime or memory footprint.

Comment: (just for those who might read it later: `.. tensor c = a[i_idx[:, None], b[i_idx]]` - there's no comma there, but I can't make <6 char post edits :) )

Answer (score 1):

Some methods :

```
i,j,k,l=[100]*4
a = np.random.randint(0,5,(i, j, k))
b = np.random.randint(0, j,(i, l))

def test1():
    # c_ilk = c[i, b[i, l], k]; shape(c) = (2,3,5)
    tmp = a[:, b, :] # <= i*ijk additional memory allocated (!) crazy
    c1 = np.diagonal(tmp, axis1=0, axis2=1).transpose([2, 0, 1])
    return c1

def test2():
    ii, ll = np.indices((i, l)) # <= 2*i*l of temporary ints allocated
    tmp2 = b[ii, ll] # i*l of ints allocated, slow ops
    c2 = a[ii, tmp2] # slow ops over tensor
    #print(c2.shape)
    return c2

def test3():
    c3=np.empty((i,l,k),dtype=a.dtype)   
    for ii in range(i):
        for ll in range(l):
                c3[ii,ll]=a[ii,b[ii,ll]]
    return c3        

from numba import jit
test4=jit(test3)
```

And the corresponding benchmarks :

```
In [54]: %timeit test1()
1 loop, best of 3: 720 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit test2()
100 loops, best of 3: 7.79 ms per loop

In [56]: %timeit test3()
10 loops, best of 3: 43.7 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit test4()
100 loop, best of 3: 4.99 ms per loop
```

That seems to show (see @Eelco Hoogendoorn comment) that your second method is nearly optimal for big sizes, while the first is a bad choice.

For numba you can just use this part of the code, and apply gradient in a non "jited" function.